# In javascript, how to redirect to SELF , with an extra variable?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to grab the current URL.
Then, append a "&p=1" to it.

And redirect it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

for this.